# Does this property of determinants generalize?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Consider the following $2\times 2$ matrix
$$
A
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Let $\Delta = a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}$ be its determinant.

Then $A$ has full rank iff $\Delta \ne 0.$

I noticed that it holds that 
$$
A 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{22} \\
-a_{21}
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{22} \\
-a_{21}
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\Delta \\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
That is: A linear combination of the columns of $A$ with coefficients that, up to their signs, consist of the elements of the second row of $A$ yields a vector that consists of a zero and the determinant of $A.$

This immediately yields that $A$ is singular if $\Delta=0:$ If all numbers in the second row of $A$ are zero, $A$ is singular. Otherwise we have found a nontrival vector in the kernel.

***Question:*** Is there a similar intuition for the determinant of $n\times n$ matrices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that generalizes...but not the way you think, probably.

1. You can use the first row instead (with alternating signs and shuffled order) and get a similar result. Alternatively, you could make a modified version of $A$ where we write
   $$
   A = \pmatrix{a & b \\c & d}\\
   A^+ = \pmatrix{d & -c  \\-b & a}
   $$
   where the elements are permuted a bit, and assigned +/- signs in a checkerboard pattern. When you do this, you find that $A^+ v = \pmatrix{\Delta\\0}$ when $v$ is the first row.  The matrix $A^+$ is called the "classical adjoint" of $A$.
2. Generalization: For $n > 2$, the classical adjoint has, in position $i,j$, the determinant of the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix you get by deleting from $A$ the $i$th row and $j$th column, multiplied by $(-1)^{i+j}$ (assuming your indexing starts at "1"). Call this $A^+$. Then it's easy to see that the first entry of $A^+ v$, where $v$ is the first row of $A$, written as a column vector, is just the standard determinant expansion; it takes just a bit more work to see that you get $0$ if the entries are those of any other row. So that's the generalization of your observation.